# Don't load div over again on change when switching from values in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a combobox with a few options to select:

```js
 $("body").on('change', '.sb-dropdown', openSbDropdown);
 
 function openSbDropdown() {

const selectedValue = $(".sb-dropdown").val();

if (selectedValue === 'everything') {
   // option 1

   } else {
   // option 2
 }
}
```

```css
 .sb-wrapper {
        display: none;
        width: 600px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 10000;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control sb-dropdown">
    <option value="everything">Everything</option>
    <option value="products">Products</option>
</select>


<div class="sb-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10">
                <div class="sb-searchresult-wrapper">
                    <div class="sb-searchresult-item">
                        <h4>Header</h4>
                        <h5>subtext</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>               
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <h4>Items 1</h4>
                <h4>Items 2</h4>
                <h4>Items 3</h4>
                <h4>Items 4</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I select a value a div will show.

Every time when I select a **new** value from the dropdown the div `sb-wrapper` will constantly load again. I only want to see the changes inside the div and not loading the div again.

How can I check if the `sb-wrapper` is already open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for visibility and based upon that use `find` to show / hide section like below.

```js
$("body").on('change', '.sb-dropdown', openSbDropdown);

function openSbDropdown() {
  if (!$('.sb-wrapper').is(':visible'))
    $(".sb-wrapper").show();
  const selectedValue = $(".sb-dropdown").val();
  if (selectedValue === 'everything') {
    $(".sb-wrapper").find('.col-2').show();
  } else {
    $(".sb-wrapper").find('.col-2').hide();
  }
}
```

```css
.sb-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control sb-dropdown">
  <option value="everything">Everything</option>
  <option value="products">Products</option>
</select>
<div class="sb-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="sb-searchresult-wrapper">
          <div class="sb-searchresult-item">
            <h4>Header</h4>
            <h5>subtext</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <h4>Items 1</h4>
        <h4>Items 2</h4>
        <h4>Items 3</h4>
        <h4>Items 4</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

`$('sb-wrapper').is(':visible')`

[jQuery docs on :visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: Thanks for your time. Do I have to call this code in my `if` statements?

Comment: Yes, sure. Check this in your if statements